# Force the user to pass a template parameter of a known type which is itself templated

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Suppose I have a class

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    T data;
};
```

where I want to enforce the fact that `T` is a known templated type. For instance, suppose that I want `T` to be a `std::vector` of something. Now one way to handle this problem would be to redefine the class so that the template parameter is also the template parameter of the data function:

```
template <typename S>
struct Foo {
    std::vector<S> data;
};
```

I do not want to do that. In this specific case, it feels more natural to require the user to construct a `foo` object like this:

```
Foo<T<S>> f;
```

which, in the case where we want `T` to be a `vector`, looks like

```
Foo<std::vector<S>> f;
```

Is there anyway to keep the first form of the class, which requiring that `T` be of a specific class? Perhaps a `static_assert`?

Comment: I am aware of that.

Comment: template template?

Comment: I don't see how a template template parameter helps here because it would not let me force the template template parameter to be a specific type (e.g. a vector). All that would let me do is perhaps suggest a default type. To my understanding...

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    static_assert( std::is_same<T,std::vector<T::value_type>>::value, "T is not a vector you idiot" );
};
```

Comment: What if `T` doesn't have `value_type`? Edit : I guess it will fail anyway, but you won't get the nice error message.

Comment: You'll need to write `std::vector<typename T::value_type>` instead of `std::vector<T::value_type>`.

Comment: I just saw the question you linked to. You are absolutely right this question is a duplicate. The answer to that question is much more general